# How do I install Laravel Collective? It keeps saying "Package requires php 7"

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

$ composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer (locked at v6.0.2) -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.2].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's because version 5.4 of "laravelcollective/html" does require php 7. Try lowering your version to 5.3

Answer (score 1):

open your composer.json, find or just append at require section.. remove ^ from the version ex : ^5.4.9.. remove ^.. it will use current version rather than installing the latest

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",
    },
```

then, `composer update`